# Python code not running in terminal in VS Code or PyCharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I'm new to programming, I've started Python with VS code and Pycharm, and I can't run my code in terminal or output tab. I've followed the steps in installing python and configuring the interpreter but i cant fix this.

[This is what i get in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMZcK.png)

[This is what i get in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ot4.png)

Comment: Never use `;` in python programs

Comment: Please include code and output as text in your question. We want that people are able to look for problems and find solutions, so we need searcheable text (in a single page). Help us to help you.

Comment: You can try to install python to some other place which does not contain 'space', your username contains 'space' can cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt by going to windows search bar and searching for it.
then enter cd "path of your folder" and press enter.Now you are in your project folder.
Now run the command "python app.py" where app.py is the name of your app.

Also please upload your code for more clarification on your question.